# RC circuit delay 200ms

Tags: circuit-design

This circuit creates a delay of 200 ms, the driver is POL power good signal.

My question is why do I need 47.5 kΩ, is this resistor part of RC delay? What is it doing?

[image: Schematic]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's providing hysteresis, the 10K and 22uF produce the timing.  The hysteresis keeps the gate from oscillating when the slowly rising edge hits its threshold.